# How to leave space between order type drop down and button search?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I work on asp.net web forms I have issue order type drop down is very

close from button search and no spaces .

so How to leave spaces between drop down order type and button search
using CSS or bootstrap .

I divide my web page to rows bootstrap but I found no space between order type drop down and search button .

so How to leave space ?

what I try

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestPage.TestPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
       <style>
        body
        {
            padding: 20px
        }
     
 
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        media="screen" />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="max-width: 400px;">
         <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Reprint ADC JDE Reports</h2>
  
         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7">
        <asp:Label ID="lblPrintServer" runat="server" Text="PrintServer"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropPrinters" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  AutoPostBack = "True" Width="220px" Height="32px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
                 </div>
             <div class="col-5">
        <asp:Label ID="lblBranch" runat="server" Text="Branch"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropBranches" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  AutoPostBack = "True" Width="220px" Height="32px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
                 </div>
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-4">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack = "True" TextMode="Date" Width="120px" Height="32px"></asp:TextBox>
                     </div>
                  <div class="col-4">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="FromTime"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromTime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Time" AutoPostBack = "True" Width="100px" Height="32px"></asp:TextBox>
                      </div>
                 <div class="col-4">
        <asp:Label ID="lblToTime" runat="server"  Text="ToTime" ></asp:Label>
           
          <asp:DropDownList ID="drpMinutes" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack = "True" Width="170px" Height="32px" >
               
          <asp:ListItem Text="--Select To Time " Value="0" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="20" Value="20" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="30" Value="30" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="40" Value="40" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="50" Value="50" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="60" Value="60" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="70" Value="70" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="80" Value="80" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="90" Value="90" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="100" Value="100" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="110" Value="110" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="120" Value="120" />
</asp:DropDownList>
                       </div>
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-4">
        <asp:Label ID="lblOrderType" runat="server" Text="OrderType"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropOrderType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="200px" Height="32px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
                         </div>
    </div>
            </div>
           
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-5">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" class="btn btn-primary" CssClass="form-control" Width="150px" Height="32px"  />
                     </div>
                 <div class="col-7">
            <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" class="btn btn-primary" CssClass="form-control" Width="150px" Height="32px"  />
                      </div>
                 </div>
          
            
       
             </div>
    
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

expected result

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8f89.png)

Comment: I think you just add `margin-top` class to the button and the problem will be solved.

Comment: can you show me please how to make that

Comment: Try add `mt-2` to the button class and see if it put space between them.

Comment: can you help me please if possible by support full answer i'm not familiar with design

Comment: `<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" CssClass="form-control" Width="150px" Height="32px"  />`
This is what i mean adding `mt-2` to the button class, you add the same with the other button and try if it work since i can't test it myself with the code above

Comment: nothing changed i add this            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" CssClass="form-control" />

Comment: Did it have style from`btn-primary` (blue background)? If not swap it to `CssClass="form-control mt-2"` ? If still not work i can't help further since i can't reproduce the sample, all i can do is guessing now.

Comment: yes working but can you show me how to do that by top margin

Comment: margin-top in this case is the class, so by adding mt-2, it will add the margin-top property to the element. To see this property and confirm the margin-top is there, you can inspect the element with the dev tools and check the "Elements" tab, search for your element and you will see it on the right side of the DevTools.

Comment: Please tag just one version of Bootstrap. It's confusing to tag multiple as syntax varies. Also, this question would be much easier to resolve if you showed rendered HTML instead of ASP code.